# Sentry Log4j2 Kotlin Spring Boot Webflux - No issues published to Sentry

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, sentry

Having trouble getting sentry issues to publish.

Here's my setup.

I have exported my DSN as `SENTRY_DSN`.

**src/main/kotlin/resources/log4j2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="warn" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.core,io.sentry.log4j2">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <Sentry name="Sentry" />
    </appenders>

    <loggers>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
            <!-- Note that the Sentry logging threshold is overridden to the WARN level -->
            <appender-ref ref="Sentry" level="WARN" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
...
dependencies {
    compile("io.sentry:sentry-log4j2:1.7.22")
    ...
}
```

**Controller.kt**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
class AuthenticationController(private val exampleService: ExampleService) {

    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger(AuthenticationService::class)

    @DeleteMapping("/session")
    fun logout(): Mono<Response> {
        logger.error("this is a error")
        return exampleService.returnMono()
    }

}
```

I expect this `logger.error` call to send a message to sentry.

Comment: Are there any sentry related entries in your log?

Answer (score 1):

Sentry SDK for Java recently got support for Webflux:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/pull/1529

That was on version 5.1.0-beta3 and GA is about to land in a few days/weeks:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#510-beta3